# Using Java agent and byte-buddy for measure execution time

Tags: java, performance, agent, byte-buddy

I am trying to create a java agent for measure execution time of a method using byte buddy lib without changing main method . I follow the tutorials and create following codes. 
When executing this MonitorInspector must give time that spend for execution. But it not working only giving the output of as follows.

Premain

Main Class

Is any way i can fix this. 
please help me to slow this problem.

This is my codes..
AgentTest( This code of agent)

```
class AgentTest {

public static void premain(String arguments, Instrumentation ins) {
    System.out.println("Premain");
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .type(ElementMatchers.nameEndsWith("Timed"))
            .transform((builder, type, classLoader, module)->builder.method(ElementMatchers.any()).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(MonitorInterceptor.class))
            ).installOn(ins);
}}
```

MonitorInspector

```
class MonitorInterceptor {
@RuntimeType
public static Object intercept(@Origin Method method,@SuperCall Callable<?> callable) throws Exception {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        return callable.call();
    } finally {  System.out.println(method + " took " +(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
    }}}
```

Main Class

```
public class SampleClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Main Class");
    Methods.test(0);


}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also achieve this by using `Advice` which uses code inlining and should result in better runtime performance:

```
class TimerAdvice {
  @Advice.OnMethodEnter
  static long enter() {
    return System.currentTimeMillis();
  }
  @Advice.OnMethodExit(onException = Throwable.class)
  static void exit(@Advice.Origin String method, @Advice.Enter long start) {
    System.out.println(method + " took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
  }
}
```

and apply the advice by

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
  .type(ElementMatchers.nameEndsWith("Timed"))
  .transform((builder, type, classLoader, module) -> 
      builder.visit(Advice.to(TimerAdvice).on(ElementMatchers.any()));
  );
```

This way, the timing does not show up in stacktraces either.

Answer (score 2):

I found good solution for this given by Rafael Winterhalter.Go to following Link [
https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/257 ]

Answer (score 0):

I see `type(ElementMatchers.nameEndsWith("Timed"))` in ur code, probably its the reason 4 the behavior of ur code